# Why the error message showing properly in Local machine, but not in QA UAT and prod Machine? What could be the possible reason?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

[image: Pic where i am not getting error]

> I have written code for file upload which will allow only some
>   particular
>       files. If user will upload any wrong extension type of file, it will through
>       error from the backend. I am doing all the validaton from backend only.
>       Error message is showing very nicely in my local machine. But when i deploy 
>       the code on QA UAT or prod error message is not showing. I am getting
>       *Typeerror: canot read property '0' of undefined*

```
In local we are notminifying the code. But in all other env it is minified.
```

Below is the code which i have written for frontend.

```js
scope.uploadFile = function (fileModel) {
          Upload.upload({
              url: scope.url,
              method: 'POST',
              fields: {'requestId': scope.requestId, 'type': scope.type, 'isFileExisted' : fileModel.isFileExisted},
              file: fileModel.file,
              fileFormDataName: 'myFile',
              sendFieldsAs: scope.form
          }).progress(function (evt) {    // Progress bar.
              fileModel.completion = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
          }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              fileModel.serverMessage = 'File uploaded successfully';
              fileModel.status = '200';
              fileModel.id = data.id;
              scope.onUpload({document: data});
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              fileModel.status = '500';
              fileModel.serverMessage =  data.errors[0].message;
              return false;
          });
        };
```

Below is the code which i have written in backend, from there i am throwing
    error message

```js
def validateDocument(String type, def file, def requestObj) {
        String errMsg

   if(type == 'treasury')
   {
    if (documents.findAll({ it.documentType == DocumentType.My_DOCUMENTS }).size() >= 5)
    {
     errMsg = "Maximum 5 attachments are allowed."
    }
    else if (documents.findAll{ it.documentType == DocumentType.My_DOCUMENTS }.find { it.fileName == file.originalFilename })
    {
     errMsg = "File with same name already exists."
    }
   }
         if (file.getSize() >= (1024 * 1024 * 5))
   {
                errMsg = "File size cannot exceed 5 MB."
            } 
   else if (!(mediaType == 'application/x-tika-ooxml' || mediaType == 'application/pdf'))
   {
                errMsg = "Invalid file format. Please add .doc .docx .xls .xlsx .pdf only"
            }
   else if (file.empty) 
   {
                errMsg = "File cannot be empty."
            } 
        }
        errMsg
    }
```

```
Please see the attached image in which i have marked an arrow, where
i am not getting error message.
```

Comment: Is it ocurring because of minification?

Comment: @[http://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq] can u help on this??

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am sorry for this question... There is no issue with the code not with the minification of the code. Actually when we arethrowing exception or error from backend with status code like(500,400,403,404). it will be filtered by other team due to security filtering. It is related to organization level of security.